# I want to set the Dropdownlist value to default value(eg : select) on each time the reset button click

Tags: c#

Hi i have a dropdownlist in my Application.
What i want is each time when i click on the Reset button it should set to default value(select).

Here is my code for reset.

```
public void ResetControl()
        {
            DDLContainer.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DDLCountryLoading.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DDLCountryDestination.SelectedIndex = 0;
            //DDLContainer.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" --SELECT--", "0"));
           ImageMode.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImageMode.ashx?Mode=A";
        }
```

Here is my dropdownlist code:

```
void ddlCountry()
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select Distinct(mCRY_VCName) from TB_TransCountry", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DDLCountryLoading.DataSource = ds;
            DDLCountryLoading.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
            DDLCountryLoading.DataTextField = "mCRY_VCName";
            DDLCountryLoading.DataValueField = "mCRY_VCName";
            DDLCountryLoading.DataBind();

            DDLCountryLoading.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" --SELECT--", "0"));

            DDLCountryDestination.DataSource = ds;
            DDLCountryDestination.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
            DDLCountryDestination.DataTextField = "mCRY_VCName";
            DDLCountryDestination.DataValueField = "mCRY_VCName";
            DDLCountryDestination.DataBind();

            DDLCountryDestination.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" --SELECT--", "0"));
            con.Close();


        }
        void ddlContainer()
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select Distinct(mCNT_VCTypeName) from TB_TransContainerType", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DDLContainer.DataSource = ds;
            DDLContainer.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
            DDLContainer.DataTextField = "mCNT_VCTypeName";
            DDLContainer.DataValueField = "mCNT_VCTypeName";
            DDLContainer.DataBind();

            DDLContainer.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" --SELECT--", "0"));


            con.Close();


        }
```

Can any one please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
    DDLContainer.Items[0].Selected = true;

Answer (score 0):

you have reset method so you can set the index by setting the SelectedIndex which starts from -1 OR you can use the property selectedValue and set the value.